# How to discard changes that are already pushed to remote?

Tags: git, version-control

I have found a couple of similar questions, and answers but those are only concerned about local commits (and answers sometimes say do not do this after sharing changes).

I have the following:

```
A-B-C-D-E (HEAD)
        ↑
      master = origin/master
```

What I want is this:

```
    someBranch
        ↓
    C-D-E (HEAD)
   /
A-B-F
    ↑
master = origin/master
```

Where F can be a commit saying that master has been reset there. Basically I want to undo the changes in C, D and E. but I don't care the reset is visible in the repository.

If this is not possible what are my closest alternatives?

*Edit:* To be clear: I am not the only one working on the project.

Answer (score 2):

A very brutal solution would be to

```
git branch someBranch
git reset --hard HEAD~3
git push --force
```

This might be acceptable if you know that nobody else has pulled the branch since you pushed to, e.g. if you are the only one working on that project. Otherwise you will probably run into problems.

Comment: make sure this is NOT set to the remote repository: git config receive.denyNonFastForwards true

Comment: My problem is that I am not the only one.

Comment: @devconsole Need a commit between reset and push to produce F

Comment: @subsub If you're not the only one then probably git revert is the way to go. This way you communicate the other devs that you indeed wanted to revert those "bad" commits. Other devs will not get into problems, but on the other hand the repo will be tainted with reverted commits and bad commits. That's the trade off you have to make.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do `git revert` on all those commits and then just push upstream. It will revert all those commits.

Comment: git revert is to generate a new commit that revert the change

Comment: The poster said that he doesn't matter if the reset is visible in the history so I thought this is also a valid approach.